# Is it right for a thread to throw an InterruptedException for itself?

Tags: java, exception

This is what I'm doing:

```
Stopwatch stopWatchToCheckTimeout;

void checkShutDown() throws InterruptedException {
  if (stopWatchToCheckTimeout.elapsed() >= MAX_GRACEFUL_TIMEOUT_DURATION) {
    throw new InterruptedException("Time to shut down now!");
  }
}

public Void mainFancyMethod() {
   try {
     while(true) {
       checkShutDown();
       // do fancy work
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     log.debug("Shutting down gracefully");
   }
   return null;
}
```

From the [java/lang/InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) documentation its not clear to me if by standards it should be another thread that should interrupt or if its okay for a thread to throw this exception for itself?

Whats the best exception to throw for this use-case?

Comment: Using exception for flow control is stated as bad design in Effective Java. As a side note, I know that it's just for an example but `InterruptedException` shoudn't be suppressed. Otherwise throwing this exception would be pointlness in your case

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel it is not really being suppressed, it is *breaking out* of the loop, terminating it (but agreed,  better set the interrupted flag or re-throw the Exception)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are using exceptions in place of control flow. Is there any reason you couldn't just have `checkShutDown` return a boolean?

```java
boolean timedOut() {
  return (stopWatchToCheckTimeout.elapsed() >= MAX_GRACEFUL_TIMEOUT_DURATION)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is correct for a thread to throw an interrupted exception, and in fact threads are usually the sources of `InterruptedException`.

In your case, I don't think it's appropriate because it has nothing to do with interruption, which is an established thread state. You just want to exit the execution, which could be done in more graceful and performant ways.

Answer (score 1):

TimeLimitExceededException: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/TimeLimitExceededException.html

From the Docs: "This exception is thrown when a method does not terminate within the specified time limit. This can happen, for example, if the user specifies that the method should take no longer than 10 seconds, and the method fails to complete with 10 seconds. "

This sounds like just what you are after, or?

Comment: a subclass of `javax.naming.NamingException`? "This is the superclass of all exceptions thrown by operations in the Context and DirContext interfaces"?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, you should not throw an `InterruptedException`.

The [Javadoc for InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) states: *Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity*. Being interrupted is a result of [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) being called on your running thread, which is not what's happening in the code you posted.

If you do still want to use an exception to break out of your loop, you should use some other exception type. However, an alternative would be to make your check method return true/false, and use that for the condition of your `while` loop. So instead of this:

```
try {
    while(true) {
        checkShutDown();
        // do fancy work
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    log.debug("Shutting down gracefully");
}
```

do something like this:

```
while (checkIfSafeToContinue()) {
    // do fancy work
}
```